# Powershell foreach with path not finding files

Tags: regex, powershell, foreach, rename

I'm trying to rename files in a specific directory by my foreach block isn't finding any files.

```
#expected encountered filename = 3000 Miles To Graceland 2001.avi
$path = "D:\Media Holding\[UsaBit.com]_3000 Miles To Graceland 2001"
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $path) {
        "FOUND ITEM"
        if (!$file.PSIsContainer) {
            $fileName = $file.FullName -replace ("(\w.*?)([12]\d{3})", "$1 ($2)") -replace("\.", " ") -replace("\s{2,}", " ")
            $fileExtension = $file.FullName -replace ("[^\.]*\.(\w{3,4})$", ".$1")
            $fileName = $fileName + $fileExtension
            Rename-Item -NewName $file $fileName
        }
    }
```

My problem is that the foreach is never getting entered. I can prove that much by the fact that my debugging message of "FOUND ITEM" is never being displayed in the console.

I had attempted to follow [K. Brian Kelly's example of a foreach](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2754/parsing-all-the-files-in-a-directory-using-powershell/). But obviously I am missing something here.

I am also attempting to rename the files and not directories found in the path based on the the replace and rename arguments I have inside the foreach. I am not certain if those are valid either and I would love if more experienced eyes could give it a once over and let me know if what I'm trying should work and if there is a better way.

Comment: `$file in Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $path`

Comment: Thanks! What's the difference between -path and -LiteralPath?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) pointed out, using:

```
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $path) {
    # ...
}
```

will work. It's the square brackets `[ ]` in your file name that are causing issues for you, and `-LiteralPath` doesn't interpret them.

They are considered special characters as of PowerShell v2, used for ranges of characters. See [Taking Things (Like File Paths) Literally](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730956.aspx).