# File not found by Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell

There is a .mp4 file in a directory. Using a wildcard, the file item is listed. However, specifying the full filename results in no listing. I tried escaping the square brackets with backtick characters, but still no listing. How can I convince `Get-ChildItem` to recognize this file?

```
C:>Get-ChildItem 'C:\src\t\t\Some*'

    Directory: C:\src\t\t

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2018-02-04     14:25              6 Some other Artist - Song Tittle [HD]-ZN9cJvl-P4c.mp4


PS 14:48  C:\src\t\t
C:>Get-ChildItem 'C:\src\t\t\Some other Artist - Song Tittle [HD]-ZN9cJvl-P4c.mp4'

C:>Get-ChildItem 'C:\src\t\t\Some other Artist - Song Tittle [HD]-ZN9cJvl-P4c.mp4' | Measure-Object

Count    : 0
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :
```

The problem with using `-LiteralPath` is that it does not work when using a wildcard since it is, well, literal. This makes me think that I have to do a `Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.mp4'`, then in a `ForEach-Object` do another `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.FullName`. Is that required? Is there no better way?

The following code does use -LiteralPath, but still fails.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter '*.mp4' |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.FullName |
            ForEach-Object {
                Rename-Item `
                    -Path $_.FullName `
                    -NewName $($_.Name -replace '(.*[\)\]])-.*(\.mp4) ','$1$2') `
                    -WhatIf
            }
    }
```

Error message.

```
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'Some other Artist - Song Tittle [HD]-ZN9cJvl-P4c.mp4' does not exist.
```

Comment: Ok. Got it. The problem is not about `foreach` as the other post implies. This, and the other post, is about `Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: No, the problem is that the file name contains [] - square brackets have a special meaning when doing wildcard matching

Comment: How can I rename this file in PowerShell?

Comment: [Use `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath` as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32469107/712649) or escape the brackets using \`

Comment: @lit `The following code does use -LiteralPath, but still fails` that's because you're still using `Rename-Item -Path` instead of `Rename-Item -LiteralPath`. You can even avoid that by using the pipeline `$_ | Rename-Item -NewName`.

Comment: Ok @briantist, thanks. I finally found `-LiteralPath` on `Rename-Item`. It works. Just using $_ from the pipeline to Rename-Item did not work without -LiteralPath.

Comment: For those reading this now, it was closed as [a duplicate to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32468103/3905079); I can't fathom why 5 people voted to reopen it, but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @lit it's not particularly relevant what the _question_ focused on, as often knowing the right question to ask depends on the knowing the answer already; rather the important thing is that the _answer_ to your question is found on the target question.